# Create Swift framework pod spec dependant on CommonCrypto

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift2, commoncrypto

I've written small library for One-Time Passwords and I'd like to make it available through CocoaPods but I'm failing at pod spec validation.

> -> OTPGenerator (1.0)
>       - ERROR | [iOS] Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
>       - ERROR |  .../OTPGenerator/OTPGenerator/HOTPGenerator.swift:19:8: error: no such module 'CommonCrypto'

Everything works fine in XCode, example project compiles without extra configuration. I added dummy `CommonCrypto` framework to the project and made actual framework dependant on it.

Is there any way to make that visible to the pod spec? I've tried multiple ways but I always end up with the same error.

Source code is available here: https://github.com/codewise/ios-otp-generators.

Comment: Check [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/tree/RNCryptor-4.0.0-beta.1#installation) installation - The Bridging Header. @RobNapier was fighting with this as well (found it on Twitter IIRC). He solved it somehow for RNCryptor-4.0.0-beta.1.

Comment: He copied headers from CommonCrypto to his library header. In my opinion it's very ugly solution but I'm going to check it anyway.

Comment: Ugly, right, but I trust @RobNapier enough to think that he tried everything to do it right before he did this.